# pg_stat_activity - is it possible to decompose a stored procedure further?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, statistics

I got a long running query in pg_stat_activity:

```
 datid | datname  | pid  | usesysid | usename |   application_name    | client_addr | client_hostname | client_port |         backend_start         |          xact_start           |          query_start          |         state_change          | waiting | state  |                      query                       
-------+----------+------+----------+---------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+--------+--------------------------------------------------
 16385 | binstore | 3325 |    16644 | bucardo | bucardo KID (fe8fe10) |             |                 |          -1 | 2015-02-02 23:45:17.133177+00 | 2015-02-03 03:37:45.894859+00 | 2015-02-03 03:37:45.926591+00 | 2015-02-03 03:37:45.926592+00 | f       | active | SELECT * FROM bucardo.bucardo_delta_check($1,$2)
(1 row)
```

The question is: is it possible to break down this bucardo.bucardo_delta_check stored procedure anyhow to get a notion of what exactly causes this query to run so long? Basically, I need an exact number of line of the SP code executing right now.

Comment: You can possibly change the function definition to emit some progress information (doing this, you may have to set `client_min_messages` or `log_min_messages`).  In this case, from the next run on, you will see what it is doing.  Changing an already running function is impossible.

Answer (score 3):

No, but given the function is read-only, one can try running it again in the concurrent session and see if the slowdown is reproducible.

If it is, try running the same queries as this function does manually. You may find them by running \sf+ on the function in psql, or, if you are running Bucardo5, by looking at the schema definition: https://github.com/bucardo/bucardo/blob/master/bucardo.schema

Answer (score 2):

There is a system view called pg_stat_user_functions. If `track_functions` has been set to `all`, you can simply do ... `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_user_functions`. `self_time` is the time needed by the function itself; if you subtract `total_time` from `self_time` you can see how long the function has spent calling somebody else.
Some some deeper profiling is not too easy as a function is mostly a blackbox.

Comment: Let me add that these data appear in that view only on call completion.  Furthermore, the data are aggregated, so for checking a single run needs some additional work.